Hipot Test Leakage Current - Canada IEC 62368-1
How do you get the leakage current parameter for hi-pot test? There is only tables for voltages in IEC 62368-1.

As I understand, this spec is for the safety of the equipment which may absorb high currents but not cause insulation breakdown during/after the event.  Power sources may absorb Vp/50 = I for example ethernet and data lines about half this current.
This is not the steady Vac Hipot leakage test for 100uA max (?), rather it is for the insulation breakdown with a crest-factored impulse at repetitive rates where levels can be from 400 V to 4kV.
ref https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva233a/slva233a.pdf?ts=1731539119749
